# Populating a list in a Firefox extension using a global js function

Tags: javascript, firefox, global, xul

I'm trying to create a new Recently Closed Tabs list in Firefox XUL.

The function to populate the list exist already and seems to rely on the class name of the menu, so I've set this to be what the function is coded for.

My simplified code (just 12 lines) is here: http://pastebin.com/2ZevfYdu
The main line is this one: onpopupshowing="document.getElementById('appmenu_history')._placesView.populateUndoSubmenu();"

At the top I am including a script which comes with Firefox. in the code I call one of its functions but nothing happens. The function in the script is expressed as follows: 
populateUndoSubmenu: function PHM_populateUndoSubmenu() { ... } 
http://pastebin.com/AZ70AqAP

I'm quite new to this. Could someone more experienced please tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: You should add `console.log()` calls here and there and check in the console to verify that it passes where you think it should.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't really looked into the console before.